# Rewriting Webpack Proxy URLs

Tags: javascript, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Webpack Dev Server to proxy my files from an external url, that's because I'm using it to develop locally and proxying the PHP/Twig files from the server, so that way I don't need to set up all the back-end locally.

But the problem is that I need to rewrite the assets urls to pull these files from my local machine, not from the proxy. Right now, when I open my localhost, all the assets are being loaded from the server. i.e: `http://mycoolwebsite.com/core/somefolder/assets/styles.css`

And I need to replace that to pull from my localhost, like this:

`/assets/styles.css`

This is what I have now:

```
devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    proxy: {
    '*': {
        target: 'http://mycoolwebsite.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
    }
}
```

Any clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you want all request that go to your server "http://mycoolwebsite.com/**"
to go to your local machine: "http://localhost:9000/" (assuming its running on port 9000)

so try this:

```
proxy: {
'/assets/**': {
    target: 'http://localhost:9000',
    secure: false,
    pathRewrite: function(req, path) {
     //use the pathRewrite to modify your path if needed
     return path;
    }
}
```

now it shouldn't make any difference what server you are actually calling. every request that includes '/assets/' should go to your localhost. (I can not test it atm)

Comment: So that's the thing. I'm proxying the website and the server is returning me the assets path pointing to itself. So the path for my css is something like `http://mycoolwebsite.com/core/somefolder/assets/styles.css`. I need to rewrite that on Webpack to render the page using the assets on my localhost.

Comment: so its somehow the other way around? I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes and no. So, let's say I'm proxying `google.com`. The Google logo path will be something like `http://google.com/images/google-logo.png`. But I want to rewrite that (and all other `google.com` entries for js, css, hrefs, etc) to get the logo from my localhost.

Comment: yes thats how I understood you and I think my updated answer is doing that, could you already try it?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried but it's not working, unfortunately.

Comment: and not working means you still get the servers data instead of the localhost data?

Comment: Exactly. Just for testing purposes, I'm trying to proxy a single file to my localhost. Like `'http://mycoolwebsite.com/assets/main.js': { target: 'http://localhost:9000/assets/main.js' }`. But the browser still doing the request to the server instead of getting this file from my local machine. Also, I don't know how it's supposed to work, but the script URL (when I inspect the element or see the source code) still pointing to the server. I had this working with Gulp and the URL changed to my `localhost` as well. Not sure if Webpack does the same though. Also, should I use pathRewrite?

Comment: do the following to be sure your request is really handled:

`pathRewrite: function(req, path) {
     console.log('path matched');
     return path;
    }`

if you have now a console output (in your IDE, not your browser) you can be sure that the path you set after the first curly bracket is correctly matching your source.